# Unable to load localhost on web browser in Raspberry pi

Tags: wordpress, apache, webserver, localhost, raspberry-pi2

I created a web server on my `Raspberry pi` using `Apache2` and `Wordpress`. At the beggining I used a local network `(IP is 192.168.1.103)` and then used a `Huawei dongle` to connect to the internet. When the dongle is connected, web browser unable to load localhost. When dongle is used it shows that:

> "The website at https://192.168.1.103/ seems to be unavailable"

How do I correct this error?

Answer (score 0):

The IP address you're using to connect to the site is a local network address.

When the device is using a mobile data dongle it's no longer connected to your local network so the local IP no longer works.

You could find out your IP address when the dongle is connected however that's impractical. There's a good chance each time you reconnect the IP address will change. Your server needs to have a static IP address.

Comment: I found the IP address using 'ifconfig' command and paste it into the browser. But it shows above result again.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot **directly** access a device on a Local network/LAN from the outside/WAN. Notice you are trying to connect to your **localhost** so you need to be directly connected to the device in question or through a medium which intenrally connects the devices together, such as a router/wifi hub.

When we break your steps down; you are trying to connect to a localhost/device on your LAN but you are connecting via dongle which is actually connecting via outside/WAN connection. This means your GET request for the localhost URL is going to the ISP/dongle providers server first then trying to get back into your LAN - this is not possible, hence the error.

Fix: Connect to device directly or via a medium such as a router (through ethernet or wi-fi).

Additionally: if you wish to type in a url instead of an IP then this will need to be resolved. This is done by manually typing in an entry in your ***hosts*** file (in the Raspberry Pi) and inputting the resoloution info i.e **www.yourwebsitename.co.uk** and local IP i.e. **127.0.0.1**.

Your webserver (i.e. Apache) may need to be restarted for changes to take effect. If site is not loading correctly then it could be that your web browser is displaying a cached image in which case simply clear cache in your web broswer and reopen.